# Is there a computationally more efficient way to compare thousands of lists to a boundary value? Python

Tags: python-3.x, performance, list-comprehension

I am comparing thousands of paths generated by a Monte Carlo simulation stored in `a` to a range of boundary values `x`. Both `a` and `x` are a list of lists. My aim is to know how many paths `a_n` in `a` (with n = 10,000 or more) never drop below each of the boundary values `x1 .... x7`. (Here, `x1 .... x7` are gently upward-sloping straight lines).

Visually, the data looks something like below, where the red line represents one of the boundary values in `x` and the cone of lines represents `a`. (There could be 7 such red lines and I want to know how many of the lines in the cone `a` never drop below each of the red lines in `x`. So an example output of the algorithm could be: `(941, 922, 893, 851, 384, 191)`.)

Currently I am doing this comparison using a list comprehension. However, when the dataset becomes large (say n = 10,000 or more in `a`) this becomes very slow. Is there a computationally more efficient way to achieve the same result?

[image: Visual representation of x and a.]

The code of the list comprehension is shown below.

```
x = [[10, 11], [14, 12]]
a = [[9, 10], [10, 11], [11, 12], [12, 13], [13, 14], [14, 15], [15, 16]]

def touch(x, a):
    return [[all([asel > xsubel for xsubel in xel for asel in ael]) for ael in a].count(False) for xel in x ]
touching = touch(x, a)
```

**EDIT**

The result I expect from the simplified example above for `a` and `x` is: `[2, 6]`. I am comparing for every list in `a` and `x`, item 1 in `a` to item 1 in `x`, item 2 in `a` to item 2 in `x`. So: a1_1 (9) (item 1 in list 1 of a) is lower than x1_1 (10). a1_2 (10), is equal to x1_2 (10) - so that is two violations of the condition. a3_1 (11) > x1_1 (10) and a3_2 (12) > x1_2 (11) and the other lists in a are also higher than their corresponding elements. For x2 (2nd list in x):, all lists in a are lower except a7, in which a7_1 (15) is higher than x2_1 and a7_2 is higher than x2_2. Hence `[2, 6]`.

Comment: Are you aware of ``any`` and ``all``, as well as generator expressions? Are you aware of the ``numpy`` library?

Comment: I am not aware of generator expressions (I am not an experienced programmer - have been struggling for days to arrive at this list comprehension). But yes, I am aware of ```numpy``` and ```np.any``` and ```np.all```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having trouble capturing your criteria...  :).  You threw in an "and/or" statement above in comments that is confusing.

This works and shows intermediate results.  You can scrub out the print statement after you get it working properly.

The comparison here is for corresponding items in `a` to be strictly less than corresponding items in `x`, for which the right answer is (1, 2).  [I was incorrect in my comment above...didn't think through it]

```
# line compare

import numpy as np

x = [[10, 11], [14, 12]]
a = [[9, 10], [10, 11], [11, 12], [12, 13], [13, 14], [14, 15], [15, 16]]

a = np.array(a)
x = np.array(x)

result = []
for row in x:
    passing = np.all(a<row, axis=1)
    print(f'for element in x: {row} the correspoinding a elements pass: {passing}')

    result.append(np.sum(passing))

print(result)
```

#### yields:

```
for element in x: [10 11] the correspoinding a elements pass: [ True False False False False False False]
for element in x: [14 12] the correspoinding a elements pass: [ True  True False False False False False]
[1, 2]
```

Comment: The criteria are a bit difficult to explain clearly. I added "and/or" because if you have a list [a1, a2] in which a1 > x2 that meets my criterion, but if a2 < x2 then I this list does not pass the test.

Comment: now you have a crosswise element comparison?  a1 to x2 within individual lists?  you can manipulate the comparison statement in the `np.all()` statement to meet your needs.

Comment: Sorry... a1 > x2 is a typo, that should be a1 > x1 ;-(

Answer (score 0):

This should be faster using numpy arrays to compare all `a` elements to each row in `x` in vectorized operations

```
# line compare

import numpy as np

x = [[10, 11], [14, 12]]
a = [[9, 10], [10, 11], [11, 12], [12, 13], [13, 14], [14, 15], [15, 16]]

a = np.array(a)
x = np.array(x)

result = []
for row in x:
    passing = np.sum(np.all(a>row, axis=1))   # sum all rows where att a>row in x
    result.append(passing)

print(result)
```

#### Yields:

```
[5, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks! The result I expect from the example is [2, 6]. I am comparing for every list in ```a``` and ```x```, item 1 in ```a``` to item 1 in ```x```, item 2 in ```a``` to item 2 in ```x```. So: a1_1 (9) (item 1 in list 1 of a) is lower than x1_1 (10). a1_2 (10), is equal to x1_2 (10) - so that is two violations of the condition. a3_1 (11) > x1_1 (10) and a3_2 (12) > x1_2 (11) and the other lists in a are also higher than their corresponding elements. For x2 (2nd list in x):, all lists in a are lower except a7, in which a7_1 (15) is higher than x2_1 and a7_2 is higher than x2_2. Hence [2, 6].

Comment: for clarity...it still isn't totally clear how you got [2,6].  In your orig post you said you wanted to know how many lists in `a` are better than each list in `x`.  There are 5 lists in `a` that are "above" x[0] as you state.  There is only 1 list in `a` that is "above" x[1].  I think we agree there...now your twist is that the lists in `a` are non-decreasing by element?  and are [2, 6] the indices of the first list that passes (one-based)?  or how do you get [2, 6]?  From the look of your data plot, it would be impossible for your lists in `a` to be non-decreasing by element?

Comment: I am only comparing items in ```a``` and ```x``` that have the same index position in the matrix. So if ```a``` lists look like this ```a = |a1, a2|``` and ```x``` lists look like ```x = |x1, x2|``` then I am checking if x1 > a1 and/or x2 > a2. There are 2 lists in ```a``` that meet this criterion for x1 and 6 lists in ```a``` that meet this criterion for x2. Hence (2, 6)

Comment: I don't think you are being consistent with your <>.  :).  In orig post you say count lists in `a` that are greater than `x`.  In your comment above you now say `a` less than `x`.  Your item explanation in the edit seems to be along original lines and support greater than, for which my count is correct.  If you want the other way, just change the `>` to `<` in my code and it will produce [2, 6]

Comment: You are right that I was inconsistent, sorry about that. However, when I change ```>``` to ```<``` I get [1, 2] for some strange reasons.